# workaround in Sqlite when triyng to compare data on empty database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am new to programming so take it easy on me. So i am reading HOUR only from SQLlite and i am checking if a current hour is the same or not as the last saved hour. My problem is when i call this method and there is no data yet in the Sqlite the app ofcourse crashes. Any idea how to solve this. So when the user launches the app for the first time the app does not crash?

```
public void CHECK(){

    sqliteDbHelper_ = new Sqlite_DBHelper(getActivity());
    sqLiteDatabase = sqliteDbHelper_.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {"hour_only","JAKOST"};
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("podatki", columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance();
    Integer currentHour = calander.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    buttonSaveOnMainPage.setClickable(true);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    Integer lastInputedHour = cursor.getInt(0);
    Log.e(TAG+"zadnja vnesena URA",""+lastInputedHour);
    Log.e(TAG+"trenutna URA",""+currentHour);
    if (lastInputedHour == currentHour){
        buttonSaveOnMainPage.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        buttonSaveOnMainPage.setClickable(false);
    }
    else
        buttonSaveOnMainPage.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        buttonSaveOnMainPage.setClickable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the count of the cursor and default to the current hour.

Something like

```
if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
    // Set default value
} else {
    // use value from cursor
}
```

Here's a link to the documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29

Comment: Alternatively, `moveToLast()` returns `false` if there is no last row.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you call your method into Try/Catch block? Check this:

```
try {
    CHECK();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: This would not really fix the problem, but would let you know which line of code was breaking.  Knowing what line of code is the problem would lead to a fix.